# Why do commas behave differently in int.Parse() and decimal.Parse() with InvariantCulture?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, globalization, cultureinfo

Why does:

```
decimal.Parse("1,2,3,45", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

return a decimal of 12345, yet:

```
int.Parse("1,2,3,45", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

throws an exception? I would expect the commas to be treated the same for the same culture. If `decimal.Parse` returns 12345, why doesn't `int.Parse` also return 12345?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[See `NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)

The default `NumberStyles` for int is `Integer`:

> Integer   Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, and AllowLeadingSign styles are used. This is a composite number style.

Compare to `Number` (used for `decimal`):

> Number    Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowTrailingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowThousands styles are used. This is a composite number style.

If you want more, use the overload that accepts `NumberStyles`, and supply (for example) `NumberStyles.Number` or `NumberStyles.Any`:

```
int i = int.Parse("1,2,3,45", NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Interesting - I didn't realise they used different styles. I can understand some of them (eg. AllowDecimalPoint), but seems strange that AllowThousands is different between the two. Thanks!